# Checked class outside of the root element proper handling

Tags: vue.js

how would I deal with a checked attribute in vuejs

```
<input :id="'todo'+id" type="checkbox" isPacked ? 'checked' : ' '>
```

which would tell me that

> - text "'checked' : ' '>" outside root element will be ignored.

That would mean if it isPacked then add a class of checked then if it's not then just remove the checked attribute

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Directly bind it.

```
<input :id="'todo'+id" type="checkbox" :checked="isPacked">
```

See [demo](https://jsfiddle.net/2arzf4pb/2/)